# Requirejs not resolving path

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have this path in require.js

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "../../../../../endeavour-ui-common/src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min",
        ....   
    },
    "shim"{
         ....
```

It is giving me

```
Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['jquery']
```

I can make sure that path is correct because same path opens the file in terminal. For example:

```
open ../../../../../endeavour-ui-common/src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
```

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: The better question is can you convert that to a URL and request that URL from a browser - that's what RequireJS does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful  [Generate URLs relative to module:](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes)

as said by @codingGorilla you will have to convert that path to a URL

```
    define(["require"], function(require) {
    var cssUrl = require.toUrl("./style.css");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be open the address from a web browser and not from the terminal.

That would mean that the path has to be relative to the webpage or to your domain root if you prefix it with /

(e.g.) if your web root is one directory up then you will do something like

```
    "jquery": "/endeavour-ui-common/src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min",
```